# How do I set a background picture?

Tags: css, html

I wrote the CSS code for background-image, but it doesn't show when set in my CSS sheet.

I tried and it only works when written in the body...

```
<body background="Tokyo.png">
```

but not in style sheet.

```
html {
  background-color: black; 
  margin: 10px;
}

body {
  background: "Images\tokyo.png";
} //CSS code in style sheet//
```

I expected background image to be shown but I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the path in `url`.

```
background-image: url("Images\tokyo.png");
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's an image you have to make sure to include url and then put the path in parenthesis like below. Also make sure your CSS is linked in the HTML.

```
body {
 background-image: url("Images\tokyo.png");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to make sure to include url and then put the path correctly in parenthesis like below. Also make sure your CSS is linked in the HTML.

`body { background-image: url("Images\tokyo.png"); }`

**Note**: If your css file is inside css directory then the path should be like-

`body { background-image: url("../Images/tokyo.png"); }`